# Why do we need to analyze oracle tables

Tags: oracle, database-performance, database-optimization

I was trying to understand how analyzing tables will be helpful to boost the performance in oracle, When optimizer is smart enough to choose the plans to process will it not get the latest stats to choose the one ?

Also giving an example and command/best analyzing method is much helpful for me to understand this concept

Comment: Then could you please get me the link , i was struggling to get the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dbms_stats.gather_database_stats
dbms_stats.gather_schema_stats
dbms_stats.gather_table_stats
dbms_stats.gather_index_stats
```

but the question is too broad
I'd recommend you look Tom Kyte "Effective Oracle by Design" chapter 6

the book on [amazon link](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Effective-Oracle-Design-Press/dp/0072230657)

similar question is here, on [AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:46582739455988) site:

Comment: I understand stats itself is broad concept in tuning but wanted to get the basic idea from experts what it does. Thanks a lot for the suggestion , will check the links.

Answer (score 0):

For Every table,  DML(UPDATE/DELETE/INSERT)  is a continuous process as applications Load, unload and perform data modifications. Now every time any query is run over databases which access these tables, Optimizer makes a cost and response be based execution plans and uses statistics to generate the optimal plan for execution

So the more precise and latest your statistics are the better plans are generated and so is your sql query performance.

we can use Analyze command to get these . Usually DB statistics collection are scheduled as jobs

Thanks,
Kalyan

Comment: The `analyze` statement is deprecated and should not be used any more. Use `dbms_stats` instead